# blackberry sync shared contacts

Tags: blackberry, synchronization, contacts

We have a Blackberry Enterprise Server, about 50 Blackberries, and Exchange 2003 with a Global Address List (GAL) set up with all the company's shared contacts (several hundred of them, or maybe a thousand).

Right now each person's Blackberry is only syncing with their personal contacts list in Outlook.  Is there a way to sync (ideally both read and write) the shared contacts folder?  Best of all, it would be nice if each contact could be designated as personal or shared, so personal contacts don't pollute the GAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing this.  Out of the box BES will not sync GAL to devices, you can buy third party software to do this (http://www.connectedsw.com/Overview/57261).

There is also the method of manually exporting the GAL to CSV and importing it into each users contacts.  I wouldn't recommend doing this though.

Is there a reason that doing an address lookups on the device isn't sufficent?  I know for me personally I wouldn't want 100's or 1000's of contacts I never email in my address book.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How do you configure address lookups using the device to check the GAL?  That might be fine, but the Blackberries here aren't seeing it.  We're by no means BES experts here so maybe we've set something up wrong.

Comment: I just foundd some software called SlipStream GALSync that does the same thing you suggested. http://www.slipstreamsolutions.co.uk/products/GALSyncServer.htm

Comment: It's a built in feature, it should just work.  When composing an email start typeing the name of the contact in the To: field and an option will come up to Lookup: "name typed".  That will bring back the contact from the GAL.